# How to delete files from a list?

Tags: xcopy

I have a filesystem that uses a hash algorithm to organize files.  I have used xcopy in the past to copy files to a different location by passing in a file that has a list of all the files and having it iterate through it.  The script looks similar to the following:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %i in (D:\foo.csv) 
do echo F | xcopy /i /d "Z:\%i\%j\%k" "Y:\%i\%j\%k" >> "D:\xcopy\Log.txt"
```

However, now I've run into a situation where in addition to copying the files that are provided in the `foo.csv` file, I want them to be deleted as well.  I looked at the xcopy documentation and couldn't find anything.  Is there someway I can accomplish this, even if I have to run another script to go through the same list of files and delete them after using xcopy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to indicate multiple commands to be excecuted by the `for` operand:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (D:\foo.csv) do (
    echo F | xcopy /i /d "Z:\%%i\%%j\%%k" "Y:\%%i\%%j\%%k" >> "D:\xcopy\Log.txt"
    del /F "Z:\%%i\%%j\%%k"
)
```

Comment: Whenever I try to run this it just keeps outputting "More?" over and over regardless of what I type.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user564636 I would need to see the actual input file you are using to dignose any further. Also take into account that you need to use %%i instead of %i if you are using this inside a .bat script

Comment: Nevermind, I was just missing a Quote. So now when I run it like that it gives me invalid # of parameters errors, but if I use a pipe (like in between echo F and xcopy commands) it's actually deleting the source files before they finish copying. Any ideas? (EDIT): I'm running it directly in the command prompt, I'm not using a batch file

Comment: @user564636 For the parenthesis thing to work you need to put it in a script, since you are supposed to put each command in a new line

Comment: As soon as I put it into a .bat file (and I had to move "do (" up to the same line as the for command because it was giving me incorrect syntax errors when ran), it worked like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Windows (I'm happily using Gnu/Linux since 1993), but perhaps you could add some command with variables like `del %n` somewhere (or replace xcopy with your own  `.bat` file doing what you want)

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it you can use [move](http://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) command instead of **xcopy**, since you're not using any extended features from **xcopy**. The '/d' is supposed to be used to only copy the files if they are newer, not sure how useful that is for your purpose since you want to delete them. Otherwise, **move** doesn't have many more options to speak of.

Another possible, and slightly more sophisticated, method is [robocopy](http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm).
`robocopy /MOVE /XO "Z:\%i\%j\%k" "Y:\%i\%j\%k"`  
The `/MOVE` would delete both folders and files after copying, and `/XO` flag excludes older files from being copied. `robocopy` is primarily available in newer operating systems (i.e. Not XP). You can check the above mentioned reference for more details.

Hope this helps. Although, just using `del` as previously mentioned should work fine also.

Comment: Does this work for lists of files? The '%k' variable is a file name, not a directory. I was under the impression robocopy could only copy/move whole directories and their contents, not specific files within them. (EDIT): Nevermind, I was missing a quotation mark

Comment: Disregard the edit, that was supposed to be for my comment on the other answer. I missed the window to edit it back out :p